# Xamarin Forms Get Grid Item Position

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a grid with  2 columns and grid populated with images. How to get the position of an image in the grid when tapped?

```
 <Grid.GestureRecognizers> 
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"                               
 </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a package for this, to easily detect taps, in a Listview way:[AiForms.CollectionView](https://github.com/muak/AiForms.CollectionView)

You can simply do:

```
 <ai:GridCollectionView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" TouchFeedbackColor="Yellow"
        ColumnWidth="100" ColumnHeight="1.0"
        IsGroupingEnabled="true" GroupHeaderHeight="36"   >
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ai:ContentCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Category}" BackgroundColor="#E6DAB9" />
                </ai:ContentCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ai:ContentCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </ai:ContentCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ai:GridCollectionView>
```

And detect tap like a listview:

```
 void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var photo = e.Item as PhotoItem;
            DisplayAlert("", $"ItemTapped {photo.Category} {photo.Title}", "OK");
        }
```

Comment: i will definitely try